# android: mapView doesnt give me correct user position

Tags: android, android-mapview

As topic I'm currently in sweden but when launching my map it shows that I'm in England.

My code looks like this:

```
private MapListener myMapViewListener;
private MapController mapController;
private GeoPoint test;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapview);
    setupListener();

    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setClickable(true);

     mapController.setZoom(7); // defualt zoom    
}

private void setupListener() {

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    MapListener listener = new MapListener();
    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            test = new GeoPoint((int)location.getLatitude()*1000000, (int)location.getAltitude()*1000000);
            mapController.animateTo(test);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
}
```

}

I've added........

```
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
</application>

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-   permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>   

  </manifest>
```

..... in my manifest.

I'm using http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html as a guide.

Very thankful for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is converting to an int before it does the multiplication so you need parens around the calculation.
Replace with this.

```
test = new GeoPoint((int)(location.getLatitude()*1000000), 
     (int)(location.getLongitude()*1000000));
```

You also might want to check out [MyLocationOverlay](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.html) if you want to draw your location on a map.

To use MyLocationOverlay.

```
MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
```

In on pause you should also call myLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation() so it doesn't drain battery when your activity is in the background.

Comment: Didn't work I even tried:                              double lat = location.getLatitude()*1000000;
       double alt = location.getAltitude()*1000000;
       test = new GeoPoint((int)lat, (int)alt);
          mapController.animateTo(test);

Comment: @Gwing-Ben Yuen You are using altitude instead of longitude.

Comment: One more question I'm trying to use "drawMyLocation" but it says it isnt visible. Is it because it is protected? What is the easiest way to get it to work?

Comment: @Gwing-Ben Yuen Updated my answer with an example of using MyLocationOverlay. You don't need to call that method. It's protected for a reason.

Comment: @Gwing-Ben you might subclass MyLocationOverlay to alter the drawMyLocation-Logic. Afaik drawMyLocation is only called, when you move the map, or if #onLocationChanged is called, and the new location is within the current viewbounds of the mapView. So you might call onLocationChanged to get drawMyLocation being invoked.

Answer (score 4):

You are actually creating the geo point wrong. You are setting the latitude and altitude here.

```
test = new GeoPoint((int)location.getLatitude()*1000000, (int)location.getAltitude()*1000000)
```

You'll want to set the latitude and longitude

```
test = new GeoPoint((int)location.getLatitude()*1000000, (int)location.getLongitude()*1000000)
```

Also try checking out the [MyLocationOverlay](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.html) class

Comment: Can you mark mine as correct? I'm beefing up my stack overflow score :)